# Working with cordova phonegap app. Created a ajax call, ajax success but no response data

Tags: android, ajax, cordova, phonegap-build

i am working with cordova phonegap app. Created a ajax call, ajax success but no response data.

It shows alert "ValidateUser failed. Please check internet connection."

Please suggest me a solution.

My ajax code shown below:

```
 var username = $('#uname').val();
 var password = $('#pass').val();
 var serviceUrl = 'www.example.com/api'; 

//alert(username+'-----'+password);
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            contentType: "application/json; charset-uf8 ",
            dataType: "json",
            crossDomain: true,
            url: serviceUrl + "/ValidateUser/?username=" + username + "&password=" + password+"&id=",
            success: function (result) {
                //alert('ValidateUser-success');
                debugger;
                if (result) {
                    var res = result;
                    if (res.Status == 0) {
                        alert("Error: " + res.Error);
                    }
                    else {

                        var user = res.User;


                             var UserID = user.UserID;
                             var UserName = user.UserName;
                             var Password = password;
                             var Description = user.Description;
                             var isGroup = user.isGroup;
                             var Expires = user.Expires;
                             var Disabled = user.Disabled;
                             var DateExpires = user.DateExpires;
                             var DateCreated = user.DateCreated;
                             var homepage = user.homepage;

                                database.transaction(function (tx) {
                                    var sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO Users

(UserID,UserName,Password,Description,isGroup,[Expries],Disabled,DateExpires,DateCreated,homepage) values(" + 

user.UserID + ",'" + username + "','" + password + "','" + user.Description + "','" + user.isGroup + "','" + 

user.Expires + "','" + user.Disabled + "','" + user.DateExpires + "','" + user.DateCreated + "','" + 

user.homepage + "')";
                    InsertUserDB(tx, sqlQuery);
                }, InsertFail, InsertSuccess);

                window.localStorage.setItem("userid",user.UserID );
                window.localStorage.setItem("username",user.UserName );
                window.localStorage.setItem("password",password );


                        }
                    }
                }
                debugger;
                window.location.href='home.html';
            },
            error: function (xhr) {
                debugger;
                alert('ValidateUser failed. Please check internet connection. ' + xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Are you applying the `whitelist` system?

Comment: Yes I have add whitelist system.

Comment: I add plugin url into my config.xml file.
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1" />

Comment: Are you looking for help? or are you wishing to play a game? There are over 8 parts to the *whitelist* system. You have just mentioned one.